# Um brasileiro entenderia "trá-los a mim"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, colocação-pronominal

Primeiramente, sou brasileiro. Eu venho tentando usar ênclise (sentem-se) em imperativo (matem), porque soa mais forte, o que mostrou algo:

Os pronomes pessoais "o(s)" e "a(s)", em ênclise em palavra terminada em -s, -z ou -r, transformam-se em "la(s)" e "lo(s)"; ex.: "ele quer fazê-la de bobo". Pela minha experiência, porque o Brasil é um país grandinho, os brasileiros entendem perfeitamente, e alguns usam, ênclise em palavras terminadas em -r (vou vê-lo amanhã), mas não sei se a entendem em palavras terminadas em -s, e principalmente em -z.

Então pergunto: os brasileiros entendem isso?

A seguir, dou exemplos, mas acharia interessante se os brasileiros e os portugueses (por favor, fala se és português ou brasileiro) comentassem, nos comentários, se entenderam todos os exemplos (se não, quais não?), assim mais pessoas conseguiriam responder:

1. Trá-los a mim (os traz a mim).
2. Tu vê-lo todo santo dia (tu o vês todo santo dia).
3. Ele fá-lo (ele o faz).
4. Nós entendemo-los (nós os entendemos) sempre, mais ou menos, às vezes, nunca.
5. Isso prá-lo (isso o praz).
6. Vós vede-lo (vós o vedes).

P.S.: agora pensando, tenho certeza de que as formas terminadas em -s seriam entendidas, porque é comum omitir o final -s em palavras e pela proximidade com o espanhol: *lo* e *la* espanhóis.

Comment: Para mim o número 3 é difícil de entender até por escrito, quanto mais falado; o verbo prazer do #5 é raramente usado; a segunda pessoa no plural, "vós" do #6, idem; os demais acho que seriam entendidos por muitos, ainda que pudessem soar não convencionais.

Comment: @stafusa, eu descobri uma coisa recentemente: as pessoas entendem a segunda pessoa do plural. Acho curioso ver que não acontece o mesmo nas conjugações da segunda pessoa do plural com ênclise.

Comment: Duvido um pouco, Schilive, especialmente um "vede-lo", acho que seria entendido por poucos. Claro que posso estar enganado, seria legal ver alguma estatística a respeito, ou ao menos uma enquete sobre isso.

Comment: @stafuaa, não, eu me expressei mal. O que eu dizer é que "vós vedes" seria entendido, mas aparentemente "vós vede-lo" não é o caso. Claro, é impossível incluir todo o Brasil, mas acho que no sul, e em SP, e em RJ,, pelo menos, seria entendido. Pode parecer estranho eu usar "pessoas" me referindo a apenas essas partes, mas até que uma boa porcentagem da população lá, mas.errei um pouco em.dizer "pessoas".

Comment: @stafusa, acho que um "vós faríeis isso" seria entendido por causa de "nós faríamos isso", a única diferença é apenas "ei". A dúvida dos não educados (o que não é um desprezo, é uma tristeza) seria, eu acho, as formas irregulares (tirando talvez "sois") e talvez pretérito perfeito (fizestes). Mas acho que as formas terminadas em "-des" seriam entendidas por contexto e talvez por eliminação.

Comment: Sim, nesse sentido concordo. Acho melhor qualificar o que quero dizer: falo "entender" diretamente, não "descobrir" depois de pensar um pouco, ou seja, um 'entender' que funcionaria numa conversa, sem gerar uma interrupção com um "como?". E, se, digamos 95% das pessoas entendem diretamente "Vocês veem suas filhas?", creio que uma porcentagem bem menor entenderia diretamente "Vós vedes suas filhas?" (Embora deva-se dizer que para uma série de outros verbos a diferença entre a 2a e a 3a pessoas é menor, e o entendimento seria mais fácil.)

Comment: @stafusa, se fores pensar, "descobrimos" palavras toda a hora. Mas acho que é inútil discutir isso, porque não sabemos a resposta de verdade

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113730/discussion-between-stafusa-and-schilive).

Answer (score 5):

Aqui em Portugal, a ênclise com infinitivos terminados em *r* não é nada problemática, talvez com raras exceções como o verbo *ir*. Quando a alternativa é entre fazer subir o clítico para um auxiliar cuja flexão termina em *-s* e deixar o clítico no infinitivo, a opção é quase sempre a última: *vamos levá-los a casa* é de longe preferido a *vamo-los levar a casa*.

Quanto a às desinências terminadas em *-s*, elas ocorrem na segunda pessoa do singular e do plural e na primeira pessoa do plural. A segunda pessoa do plural é irrelevante, porque é arcaica na maioria do país. Resta-nos a segunda do singular e a primeira do plural. Para a segunda, questão coloca-se mais em Portugal, devido a dois fatores:

1. O uso generalizado do tratamento por tu com desinências verbais da 2ª pessoa do singular, que está rapidamente a ganhar terreno aos tratamentos na 3ª pessoa na maioria das situações sociais.
2. O facto de a ênclise ser o padrão normal de colocação, e de estar a ganhar terreno à próclise, mesmo entre as camadas mais cultas.

Para a primeira do plural, em Portugal a questão é também mais pertinente, porque *a gente* é também menos usado do que no Brasil.

A minha impressão geral é de que ênclise é problemática nestas situações para muitos falantes, talvez até mais na segunda pessoa do que na primeira. Especialmente nas camadas menos cultas, é frequente a forma *-o* ser usada em lugar de *-lo*, por exemplo *tens-o aqui* (com o *s* lido /z/) em lugar de *tem-lo aqui*.

As formas em *-z* da terceira pessoa são um pouco menos problemáticas, embora *faz-o* e *traz-o* não sejam exatamente inauditas. Curiosamente, um erro frequente entre pessoas cultas é rejeitar *faze-lo* e dizer *(tu) fá-lo*.

Em todo o caso, há quase sempre estratégias para evitar a ênclise nesta situações: omitir o objeto ou usar *isso* em lugar do clítico, por exemplo.

Duas correções:

> **Traz-mos a mim** (não **trá-los a mim**).
> **Isso praz-lhe** (não **prá-lo**).

Comment: Creio que *traz a mim* é gramatical no português brasileiro. Se for, imagino que *trá-los* também há de ser.

Comment: «A segunda pessoa do plural é irrelevante».  *Entra a gente do norte*

Answer (score 3):

Uma resposta sucinta de um falante nativo de pt-BR, sem ter feito nenhuma pesquisa de campo a respeito e sem referências.

**Um brasileiro entenderia “trá-los a mim”?**

- Acredito que, em um primeiro momento, independente do nível educacional, a imensa maioria dos brasileiros não o entenderia.  E quem porventura o entendesse, achá-lo-ia **hilário ou pedante.**
- Na língua escrita, com mais tempo para pensar, o entendimento talvez seja um pouco mais fácil. Como sempre, o contexto é de grande importância para uma comunicação eficaz.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Acho que a mesóclise está errada, por causa.do "não".

Comment: @Schilive  Tens razão.

Comment: como Brasileiro, eu entenderia. Acharia estranho, mas entenderia... Aprendemos na escola a forma correta e falamos informalmente de forma diferente.

Comment: @Peixoto   Acho que seu comentário ficaria mais sincero e esclareceria mais, se você tivesse acrescentado: "como brasileiro com nível superior, bilingue, estudioso e que (provavelmente) frequentou boas escolas, eu entenderia."  Na minha profissão, eu lido diariamente, e ao vivo, com pessoas de todos os níveis educacionais e tenho a certeza de que se eu dissesse "trá-los a mim", a imensa maioria ficaria olhando para mim com um ponto de interrogação na testa.

Comment: Como na tua resposta está dito: "Independente do nível educacional", por isso, citei meu exemplo. Eu acredito que a maioria das pessoa que foram meus colegas no ensino secundário, entenderiam, pois era dessa forma que meus professores de português e literatura falavam. Obviamente, sabemos que o Brasil é enorme e no Sul temos uma forma muito peculiar de falar que não é a mesma do resto do Brasil.

Answer (score 1):

(**Sou brasileiro**)

> Trá-los a mim (os traz a mim).

- Creio que a grande maioria dos brasileiros iríam entender, mas acharam um pouco estranho, apenas os que não estudaram muito ou que não leram muito poderiam ficar meio perdidos mais ainda sim compreenderiam

> Tu vê-lo todo santo dia (tu o vês todo santo dia).

- Mesmo não sendo muito comum algumas partes do Brasil utilizam essa expressão *todo santo dia*, por isso creio que compreenderiam a frase.

> Ele fá-lo (ele o faz).

- Essa eu acho mais difícil aqui as pessoas entenderem, creio que o *ele o faz* seja melhor para entendimento, eu mesmo não entendi muito bem essa frase.

> Nós entendemo-los (nós os entendemos) sempre, mais ou menos, às vezes, nunca.

- Essa creio que todos consiguirão entender com facilidade, pelo menos eu não tive problema.

> Isso prá-lo (isso o praz).

- Sinceramente, ainda não entendi o que essa frase siginifica, creio que não é muito utilizada onde eu moro e nem nos livros que eu já li

> Vós vede-lo (vós o vedes).

- Nunca ouvi essa frase,(*vós vede-lo*), mas consegui entender o que significa, creio que algumas pessoas não iram conseguir entender no momento, precisaram refletir um pouco.

(Não sou estudante de português nem nada parecido com isso, sou apenas um amante de livros, com isso já li várias frases "incomuns", com isso não levem o que eu escrevi como verdade absoluta, se perceberem algum erro comentem, ficarei grato com a ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a Frase 3,  eu como brasileiro não entenderia se alguém nao me explicasse !
Falando ou lendo eu não conseguiria entender se não tivesse o significado ao lado, poucas vezes ouvi alguém falar essa frase,então acho que ela já não é mas tão usada! Por esse fato muitos brasileiros não sabem o seu significado!
As outras eu conheço todas até pq tenho uma amiga que usa bastante frases nesse contexto aí